# android studio with opencv libraries linking error

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I should say that I'm first time at android studio with ndk.
environment is **Android Studio 3.1.4** and **OpenCV 3.4** at **windows 10** os.

I use open source about opencv that 'Facetracker' link is below
 https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker
i changed some codes and want to build at android studio
so i drew up `CMakeList.txt`, `Android.mk`, `Application.mk`, `build.gradle`.
Synchronization with gradle work well but build, generate signed APK occur error below.

```
   Build command failed.
    Error while executing process C:\Users\Duru\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\ProgramFiles\Android\Projects\OpencvTest\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86_64 --target PAW}
    [1/1] **Linking CXX shared library** ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86_64\libPAW.so
    FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Duru\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-g++.exe  --sysroot=C:/Users/Duru/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Duru/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -std=gnu++11 -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot C:/Users/Duru/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libPAW.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86_64\libPAW.so CMakeFiles/PAW.dir/src/main/jni/src/lib/PAW.cc.o  -latomic -lm "C:/Users/Duru/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
    D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:648: error: undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'
    **D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:648: error: undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2686: error: undefined reference to 'cv::MatConstIterator::seek(long, bool)'
D:\ProgramFiles\Android\Projects\OpencvTest\app\src\main\jni\src\lib/PAW.cc:146: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2591: error: undefined reference to 'cv::MatConstIterator::seek(int const*, bool)'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2591: error: undefined reference to 'cv::MatConstIterator::seek(int const*, bool)'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:2686: error: undefined reference to 'cv::MatConstIterator::seek(long, bool)'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:717: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:717: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
D:\ProgramFiles\Android\Projects\OpencvTest\app\src\main\jni\src\lib/PAW.cc:167: error: undefined reference to 'cv::remap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'

    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

my `android.mk`

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
CVROOT := D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni
LOCAL_MODULE := FaceTracker
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libFaceTracker.a #$(wildcard /src/lib/*.cc)
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS   = -lz -lm
LOCAL_CFLAGS   = -Wall -pedantic -g -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on


include $(CVROOT)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_C_FLAGS+= -DNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(NDK_APP_PROJECT_PATH)/stasm4.1.0/stasm
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NDK_APP_PROJECT_PATH)/libstasm.a
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(NDK_APP_PROJECT_PATH)/stasm/*.cpp)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libandroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += FaceTracker
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
endif
```

my `build.gradle`

```
    import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def getNdkBuildPath() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

    def command = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
    if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        command +="\\ndk-build.cmd"
    } else {
        command +="/ndk-build"
    }
    return command
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.duru.opencvtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc',
                        '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary342')
}
```

my `application.mk`

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-28
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11
APP_OPTIM := release
```

and CMakeList.txt

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(pathOPENCV D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk)
set(pathPROJECT D:/ProgramFiles/Android/Projects/OpencvTest)
set(pathLIBOPENCV_JAVA ${pathPROJECT}/app/src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)


set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${pathOPENCV}/sdk/native/jni/include)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib


             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/jni/native-lib.cpp)

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
add_library( Tracker SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/Tracker.cpp )
add_library( PDM SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/PDM.cc )
add_library( PAW SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/PAW.cc )
add_library( Patch SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/Patch.cc )
add_library( IO SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/IO.cc )
add_library( FDet SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/FDet.cc )
add_library( FCheck SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/FCheck.cc )
add_library( CLM SHARED src/main/jni/src/lib/CLM.cc )


set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathLIBOPENCV_JAVA})


# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       Tracker
                       PDM
                       PAW
                       Patch
                       IO
                       FDet
                       FCheck
                       CLM

                       lib_opencv

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

opensource are composed of 7 header, 6 .cc files and a .cpp file.